# How does this reverse() function work in the below code?

Tags: c, pointers, reverse

I found this code on the Internet which reverses strings in C using pointers. 
I understand the most of it but I don't understand the `reverse()` function: why it is using `length / 2`?

If I change the condition in second `for` loop to `length` in `reverse()` function, it also displays the same output.

```
// function to reverse the string s which is an array of some size
void reverse(char *s) {
    int length, c;
    char *begin = NULL, *end = NULL, temp;

    length = string_length(s);
    begin = s;
    end = s;

    for (c = 0; c < length - 1; c++)
        end++;

    for (c = 0; c < length / 2; c++) {
        temp = *end;
        *end = *begin;
        *begin = temp;

        begin++;
        end--;
    }
}

int string_length(char *pointer) {
    int c = 0;

    while (*(pointer + c) != '\0')
        c++;

    return c;
}
```

Comment: Try to execute this code by hand on a small string and you will see why ;)

Comment: I did and sorry if I sound stupid but I still don't understand "length / 2" part is doing things. I understand the logic when its 'length  - 1'. I am just a beginner

Comment: If you go over `length/2` you will revert all the changes you did and you end up with the original string unchanged.  Imagine `abcdef`: 1) `swap(a,f)` 2) `swap(b,e)` 3)`swap(c,d)`. ideally you should stop now and you would end up with: `fedcba`. If you continue then you will execute:  4) `swap(c,d)`, 5) `swap(b,e)`  6) `swap(a,f)` and you would end up with...... `abcdef` again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use a trivial comparison:

- you have a ball in each hand, say a black one in the right hand and a white one the left hand.
- if you swap the balls once, you have effectively reversed the situation.
- but if you swap the balls twice, you are back in the original situation.
- hence the number of swaps must be half the number of balls.

The same goes for the letters in the string, if you perform `length` swaps, you will get the original string. To get a reversed string, you must stop at half the length of the string.

Note also that the code is more complicated than required.  Here is a simplified version:

```
// function to reverse the string s which is an array of some size
void reverse(char *s) {
    char *begin, *end;

    for (end = begin = s; *end; end++)
        continue;

    while (begin < end) {
        char temp = *begin;
        *begin++ = *--end;
        *end = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks  chqrlie, this code is much better than the one I mentioned. By the way, can you suggest me from where should I learn C? I just want to become better with C

Comment: That's a difficult question. I don't have a definitive answer to it. I suggest you read the K&R book *The C Programming Language*, but the examples are quite outdated. You must also have a good programming environment to learn C programming and debugging. What system do you use?

Comment: Currently, I am using windows in my laptop. I use VS Code to compile and run my code. I use ~MinGW~ compiler with ~gcc~ debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at what is done in the loop:

```
temp = *end;
*end = *begin;
*begin = temp;
```

This is some typical swap code that here swaps two characters `*begin` and `*end` of a string. The pointers iterate from the beginning and the end of the string and approach the middle.

Using the minimal example `abcd`, let's see how many characters we have to swap:

```
abcd (Original string)
dbca (Swapped 'a' and 'd') - iteration 1
dcba (Swapped 'b' and 'c') - finished after 2 iterations
```

So you only need to swap half of the characters (`length / 2` iterations) because you change two of them with each operation. This also explains why you get the original string when changing to `length - 1` iterations:

```
dcba (result from above after 2 iterations)
dbca (Swapped 'c' and 'b') - iteration 3
abcd (Swapped 'd' and 'a') - original string after 4 iterations
```

Answer (score 0):

Because when c is 0, you will swap the elements at `s[0]` and `s[length-1]`. When c is 1, you will swap the elements at `s[1]` and `s[length-2]` and so on. If you used `length` instead of `length/2` you would reverse the string and then reverse it back to the original.